# Create Average of Monthly Data to Quaterly Data in Panel Data using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, converters, panel-data

I've got the following dataset:

```
     Date Country         Specie  Monthly Average  \
 Apr 2015       BR             co         5.840000   
 Apr 2015       BR            no2         7.553704   
 Apr 2015       BR             o3        15.561667   
 Apr 2015       BR           pm10        16.283333   
 Apr 2015       BR           pm25        51.633333
```

...         ...     ...            ...              ...

For 10 countries, for certain emissions (specie) with months of 2015 to 2021. I want to convert them into quarterly average data (using the average of the corresponding months in a quarter) of the following form as an example:

```
     Date Country         Specie  Quarterly Average  \
 2015 Q1       BR             co         6.840000   
 2015 Q1       BR            no2         9.553704   
 2015 Q1       BR             o3        17.561667   
 2015 Q1       BR           pm10        18.283333   
 2015 Q1       BR           pm25        55.633333
```

...         ...     ...            ...              ...

How it would be possible to do this in python pandas?

Also I've got another question, If I want to make a separation of Specie in columns and take the corresponding values, how it would be possible, in the way that I can obtain the following structure:

```
     Date Country         co Average       no2 Average   o3 Average      ...    \
 2015 Q1       BR           6.840000      9.553704   17.561667 
 2015 Q2       BR           8.840000      10.553704   18.561667
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a `Quarter` column from original `Date` column

```py
df['Quarter'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.to_period('Q')
```

Then Groupby `Country`, `Specie` and `Quarter` columns, calculate mean of `Monthly Average` column in each group. Rename the result column as `Quarterly Average`.

```py
df_ = df.groupby(['Country', 'Specie', 'Quarter'], as_index=False)['Monthly Average'].mean().rename(columns={'Monthly Average': 'Quarterly Average'})
```

FYI, [pandas.pivot_table()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) is what you want to obtain the structure.